# Changing IP address of selenium chrome on the fly using python

Tags: python, selenium

I have been trying to change the IP address of selenium chrome without closing browser instance or launching the new instance (dont want to loose the progress of crawling by launching new instance), but haven't found the way to do it yet. There are some examples available on [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776607/python-selenium-webdriver-changing-proxy-settings-on-the-fly) but none of them kind of working. Is there a way to change the proxy?

Comment: any progress in here?

Comment: Nope, only possible way for it to either re-launch the browser with different IP or use firefox.